# rsync only sync destination folder existing files

Tags: rsync

Src folder: A.txt B.txt C.txt
Dst folder: B.txt

Is there any way to let rsync only sync files in destination folder? So if A and B in source folder updated, rsync only copy B to destination folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rsync --existing` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `--files-from` option which gives you more flexibility in controling what files would be transfered.

In your example, you can run `find >/path/to/files_to_be_synced` in your `Dst` folder, and then run `rsync --files-from=:/path/to/files_to_be_synced`, then only the files in `files_to_be_synced` will be transfered.

Note the colon ( : ) in command `rsync --files-from=:/path/to/files_to_be_synced`. It means read the `files_to_be_synced` file from remote server. You can alsa read the file from local server by omit the colon.